# How to make subsequent api calls in effects ngrx?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, angular14

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { loadDataSuccess, loadDataFailure } from './data.actions';

@Injectable()
export class DataEffects {
  loadData$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[Data] Load Data'),
      mergeMap((action: any) =>
        this.http.get(`/api/data/${action.payload}`).pipe(
          map((data: string[]) => {
            const objects = data.map(str => ({ value: str }));
            return loadDataSuccess({ data: objects });
          }),
          catchError(error => of(loadDataFailure({ error: error.message })))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

In reference to the above code, I need to make api for each element in the data array.
The returned response should be dispatched as another action which will eventually get stored in store.

But I need this array of strings to be stored in the store as well.
How do I implement such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `map` you can use `concatMap([])` to dispatch individual actions.
In the example below you can replace `action` with `loadDataSuccess`.

```
import { of, concatMap, map } from 'rxjs';

of(['one', 'two', 'three'])
  .pipe(concatMap(a => a), map(i => 'action: ' + i))
  .subscribe(console.log);


// Output:
// action: one
// action: two
// action: three
```